# Convert server 2012 R2 to Windows 10

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10, licensing

I have a server machine, with regular desktop hardware that I have obtained from my company. It is currently running Windows Server 2012 R2. The intention is to use it as a media server, connected to a TV.
It works well, but the server OS is very heavy and slow to boot, also not 100% compatible with some of the applications I want to run on it, so I would like to install standard Windows 10 on it.
Does anyone know if the server license will work for Windows 10, and which version of Windows 10 (home/pro/enterprise) I could install?

Comment: There are better forums for your question.

Comment: Direct me to them and I'll gladly remove the question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to buy a Windows 10 license. OEM are the cheapest. Retail will allow you to move the license on another hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I assumed as much, but couldn't find anything conclusive on the Microsoft sites.